# webservice call by johnpet

Tags: ios, webservice-client

I've been stuck on this problem for weeks now so I would really appreciate some help. I'm trying to send an HTTP Post with the ios application that I'm developing but the push never reaches the server although I do get a code 200 as a response (from the URL connection).

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)webservice_Call

{

  NSString *urlString=@"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.1/find/city?lat=10.369&lon=122.5896";

  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                                   timeoutInterval:10];

  [request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];

  NSError *requestError;

  NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;


  NSData *response1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];

  NSDictionary *resDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response1 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:Nil];

}
```